# Embed Barcode in C# PDF Library

Tags: c#, .net, pdf, embed, barcode

I want to generate a delivery note with a Windows Form Application. Therefore I have included the PDF File Writer into my project (http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/570682/PDF-File-Writer-Csharp-Class-Library-Version).

I want to embed the Barcode39 font for some barcodes. I have Barcode39 installed on my pc and embedded it in my code:

```
BarcodeFont = new PdfFont(Document, FontName3, FontStyle.Regular, true);
```

When I run my program I get the following error:

> Required font file table is missing

I have searched on Google for this error, but I did not found anything about a 'font file table'.

What do I wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Please note the PDF File Writer C# Class Library (Version 1.5) supports barcode. The supported codes are Code-39, Code-128, UPC-A and EAN-13. This support is without using fonts.